# Global accessible mvc web application configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, configuration

As soon as my web application starts, it loads a few database connection parameters out of a custom configuration file (! not *web.config*), creates a database instance and needs to fetch about 120 different parameters from the database that are needed to work correctly. My question is now - what is the best way to make them globally accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a static wrapper around it with a property for every parameter or a dictionary containing all the parameters:

```
public static class ConfigParams
{
    // Either properties for every parameter:

    public static string Culture { get; set; }

    public static string WebsiteTitle { get; set; }

    public static DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }

    // Or a dictionary containing all the properties accessed by a string:

    Dictionairy<string, object> Params { get; set; }    
}
```

And access them like this:

```
string culture = ConfigParams.Culture;
```

Or with the dictionary:

```
string culture = ConfigParams.Params["Culture"].ToString();
```

Comment: Is this a common method or do I face serious downsides from it regards to a clean mvc implementation? If there's one thing I learnt from ASP MVC4 is that Microsoft is very serious about doing things their way.

Comment: @Acrotygma MVC itself does not offer a solution for problems like this. You could also create a service with an interface and use an IoC framework to inject the implementation. It really depends on your application architecture.